# Rebase one branch with same but updated commit onto another branch

Tags: git, github, version-control

My colleague and I are coding one feature that was decomposed into 2 tasks. Let his branch be forked from `develop` and be named `task-1`. My branch is based on his work and therefore is forked from `task-1` and is named `task-1.1`. The styleguide requires us to have one personal commit for each task (one task branch - one commit). Than means in the result we need to have 2 commits of our tasks be merged into `develop`.
So he does some major work on `task-1` and creates a commit (from which I fork my `task-1.1` branch), he pushes his branch to remote repo, then keeps on working and when performes more changes, he doesn't create new commit, but squashes his changes into the first and only one, then pushes it to remote with the following combination:

```
git commit --fixup HEAD
git rebase -i --autosquash HEAD~2
git push --force
```

here is when the problem begins - I need to rebase my `task-1.1` onto his updated `task-1` branch, so that his updated work be included into my branch. But he didn't add any more commits, he has the same commit that was changed. How does git recognize that it was changed and needs to be rebased? As I understand it, I need to reset his local branch first with `git reset --hard origin/task-1` and than switch to my branch `git switch task-1.1` and rebase his work `git rebase task-1`. Will this rebase of the same commit update proberly his commit in my branch and won't it create bugs/conflicts?

Answer (score 1):

In short, git won't automatically recognize the same commit when doing a rebase unless the commits are exactly the same. I've recreated a situation that I believe is similar to yours below. I have two branches `task-1` and `task-1.1`.

Task 1 looks like:

```
commit 4750f0aa91507ff37758470498e4fc1bd8b311a2
Author:
Date:   Fri Jul 29 07:48:22 2022 -0400

    Add 'New Code' to file

commit 831f9084ef2da751e22c755240ce38f7017cc066
Author:
Date:   Fri Jul 29 07:47:33 2022 -0400

    Add future task

commit 6ce66ebae079f2882806bb2ac54d83949d54f188
Author:
Date:   Fri Jul 29 07:36:17 2022 -0400

    Add hello
```

Task 1.1 looks like:

```
commit 89941e16a89648ecebbea643ea947eb2d5825d9b (HEAD -> task-1.1)
Author:
Date:   Fri Jul 29 07:37:41 2022 -0400

    Add task-1.1.txt

commit 6ce66ebae079f2882806bb2ac54d83949d54f188
Author: 
Date:   Fri Jul 29 07:36:17 2022 -0400

    Add hello
```

I'm now going to add a new file called `test2.txt` to `task-1` and used the same set of commands as your colleague.

```
# git commit --fixup=HEAD changes the history like this:

commit 87a2fb8d049d538ab9cb9891836ae943a90b7e08 (HEAD -> task-1)
Author:
Date:   Fri Jul 29 07:50:30 2022 -0400

    fixup! Add 'New Code' to file

# git rebase -i --autostash HEAD~4 changes the history like this:
# (I had extra commits that needed to be squashed)

commit 747e180e386645f1e50ae094ce77b651d406b9db (HEAD -> task-1)
Author:
Date:   Fri Jul 29 07:36:17 2022 -0400

    Add hello
```

We can confirm that the commits are indeed squashed together by showing the stat of the HEAD commit.

```
commit 747e180e386645f1e50ae094ce77b651d406b9db (HEAD -> task-1)
Author:
Date:   Fri Jul 29 07:36:17 2022 -0400

    Add hello

 future_task.txt | 2 ++
 hello.txt       | 1 +
 test2.txt       | 1 +
 3 files changed, 4 insertions(+)
```

Now we're ready to try and rebase your changes to get the latest from his branch. When you rebase, you can simply rebase onto `origin/task-1` after running a `git fetch`. That way you don't have to switch branches and pull.

If you run the following `git rebase -i origin/task-1`, you'll get a conflict due to the similar changes in `6ce66ebae07` and `747e180e3866`. When you're dumped to the command line and informed of the conflict, you can choose to run `git rebase --skip` to drop your copy of the `6ce66ebae07` and keep your colleague's `747e180e3866`. You can also set your `6ce66ebae07` to `drop` during the interactive rebase above to completely bypass the conflict. This would look like the following:

```
drop 6ce66ebae0 Add hello
pick 89941e16a8 Add task-1.1.txt
```

After setting 6ce66ebae0 to drop and continuing with the rebase we get the following:

```
commit d3806a32c18fd5382837194fc560872f8c6bf06a (HEAD -> task-1.1)
Author:
Date:   Fri Jul 29 07:37:41 2022 -0400

    Add task-1.1.txt

commit 747e180e386645f1e50ae094ce77b651d406b9db (task-1)
Author:
Date:   Fri Jul 29 07:36:17 2022 -0400

    Add hello
```

Hopefully that demonstration helps.